# Showing a WPF window after the binding has been performed

Tags: wpf, delay, show, xmldataprovider

I have a WPF window that is shown after clicking a button on the screen. The window builds a table dynamically using an XmlDataProvider. The problem I'm experiencing is that on calling the Show() method, the window is shown in a collapsed mode for a very brief amount of time and then it becomes bigger as the data from the XML file gets populated. Is there any way to delay the display of the window until the data has been populated in order to avoid this unpleasant visual effect?

Thanks in advance for your input!

--Nacho

Comment: you create the items in the new window 'code-behind'?,

Comment: No, the items are populated using XPath in the XAML code itself. Nothing related to the window loading process takes place in the code-behind file.

Comment: I have the same problem after about 10 years ... :(